# Questions with (multiple) Answers but no votes

Tags: discussion, voting

Fairly uniquely amongst the stacks I belong to I often see Questions on ELL with answers (sometimes multiple answers), but no votes on the question itself.

While asking about things like this on meta are often preaching to the choir, is there anything that can be done with the settings for ELL to get people to upvote questions more? Just looking a the front page today there's a question with three answers and zero votes on the question. Surely if it's worth answering it's worth an upvote?

Comment: Why do you think answering a question has anything to do with whether it is worthy of an upvote? Upvotes are indicators that other readers might find the question interesting or useful. Someone being willing to help the author and answer the question doesn't magically make that question worthy of an upvote. If you want to see more questions upvoted, help the authors improve the quality of their questions so more people believe they are worth upvoting.

Comment: Related: [Flaws in the voting model in re. questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3290/9161), [How can we improve our voting system?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2784/9161), and [Finished seeing the contents? Now, wait a sec.! Did you vote?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/814/9161)

Comment: This is a valid concern but far from unique across Stack Exchange. Even communities with an (IMHO) very healthy voting culture notice this: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9649/8732

Comment: If the question wasn't worth a single click, how was it worth writing several paragraphs for?

Comment: @Nij Your standards are lower than mine. I would never downvote a question I answered, but if I'm going to recommend a question to other people, a question needs to be more than answerable. Wanting to help someone by answering their question is different from marking their question as a good example for others to follow. I think the language barrier makes ELL different. I don't feel the same compassion for people asking a mediocre question in their native language.